# Can measuring a linear combination of signals improve SNR?

Tags: probability, estimation

The system is described as follows:

$y= max(M x + n,0),\quad n|x \sim N(0,\sigma _0^2+\alpha M x)$

With parameters:

$ x\in \mathbb{R}_{q\times1}^+ ,\quad \mathbb{E}[x_i]\approx\sigma_0, \quad M\in[0,1]_{p\times q},\quad \alpha,\sigma_0\in \mathbb{R}^+, \quad p\leq 3q $

And a definition for SNR:

$ SNR=\frac{\mathbb{E}[x]}{\mathbb{E}[\sigma(M^{-1}(n|x))]} $

If we look at the simple case where $M$ is the identity matrix, the independent noise attenuates the SNR significantly.

Is there a choice of $ M $ which is better in terms of SNR than the identity matrix (or a stack thereof)?

On the one hand the SNR of each measurement $ y_i $ improves because the sum of signals reduces the effect of the independent noise.
On the other hand, since $ M^{-1} $ usually has negative values this means that while the signals are subtracted, the noises always add up and this reduces the SNR.